# Server's socket not outputting data unit client code stops running

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I am playing around with networking and trying to send a simple message over my network using sockets in Java.

Here is the server code:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String clientSentence;
        String uppercaseSentence;

        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);

        System.out.println("Server Running.");
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Client message received: " + clientSentence);
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String originalSentence;
        String modifiedSentence;

        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6789);

        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence: ");
        originalSentence = inFromUser.readLine();

        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        outToServer.writeBytes(originalSentence);
        System.out.println("Message Sent");
}
```

When I run them both and input a message into the client side, there is no confirmation on the side of the server in the console, however there is confirmation on the client side that a message has been sent. If I then end the client and stop it running, the server will output the sent message to the console them immediately throw an error.

I think it has something to do with the actual BufferedReader not actually getting the message or something?

Again I am very new to networking so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You never flush or close the output Stream.

Comment: It was a sample of code, the issue was when I sent the message from the client I didn't add a new line at the end of the string

Comment: Note that I think that it is good practice to be more "symmetric" when doing I/O such as this, meaning that if you're going to send data using a `DataOutputStream`, then best to read the data in as a `DataInputStream`. If you're only sending Strings though, I would use a Writer such as a PrintWriter and then read with a Reader.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Please clarify.

Comment: As usual. You are reading lines in the server but you aren't writing lines in the client. Add a line terminator, or use one of the numerous methods that sends one for you. NB If you're using `BufferedReader` in the server you should be using a `Writer` in the client, and *vice versa.*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is symmetry in how one connection sends data and how the other side receives the data. So, if the client is sending data via a `DataOutputStream`, then best to read the data in as a `DataInputStream`. If OTOH, you're only sending Strings, I would use a Writer such as a PrintWriter and then read with a Reader. I would send each line via `println(...)` and would call `.flush()` on the PrintWriter to ensure that the buffer sends the line when desired. For example, a simple client could look like so:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {
    public static final String EXIT = "exit";
    public static final int HOST_ID = 6789;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        // using try-with-resources so that I close all streams when done
        try (
            BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", HOST_ID);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        ) {     
            String input = "";
            do {
                System.out.print("Please enter a sentence, or \"exit\" to exit: ");
                input = inFromUser.readLine();
                out.println(input);
                
                // flush the output stream to send all pending bites:
                out.flush();  
                
            } while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase(EXIT));

            System.out.println("All Done");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and the Server could look like:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // using try-with-resources so that I close all streams when done
        try (
            ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(welcomeSocket.accept().getInputStream());
        ) {
            System.out.println("Server Running.");
            System.out.println("socket accepted");

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String text = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("text: " + text);
                System.out.println("uppercase: " + text.toUpperCase());
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```